# Understanding the different behavior of thunks when GHCi let bindings are involved

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, ghci, thunk, weak-head-normal-form

I've been playing with some examples from Simon Marlow's book about parallel and concurrent
programming in Haskell and stumbled across an interesting behavior that I don't really understand. This is really about me trying to understand some of the inner workings of GHC.

Let's say I do the following in the REPL:

```
λ» let x = 1 + 2 :: Int
λ» let z = (x,x)
λ» :sprint x
x = _
λ» :sprint z
z = (_,_)
λ» seq x ()
()
λ» :sprint z
z = (3,3)
```

Ok, this is pretty much what I expected except that z gets evaluated to WHNF already. Let's write a similar program and put it in a file:

```
module Thunk where

import Debug.Trace

x :: Int
x = trace "add" $ 1 + 2

z :: (Int,Int)
z = (x,x)
```

And fiddle around with it in GHCi:

```
λ» :sprint x
x = _
λ» :sprint z
z = _
λ» seq x ()
add
()
λ» :sprint z
z = _
λ» seq z ()
()
λ» z
(3,3)
```

So this behaves a little different: `z` is not evaluated to WHNF in advance. My question is:

Why is `z` evaluated to WHNF in the REPL when doing `let z = (x,x)` but not when loading the definition from a file. My suspicion is that
it has something to do with pattern binding but I don't know where to look that up for clarification (maybe I'm just completely utterly wrong). I would have expected it to somehow behave like the example in the file.

Any pointers or a brief explanation why this happens?

Comment: Because `(,)` is a constructor, the difference makes no difference to Haskell's semantics (`:sprint` gives access to internal thunk implementation details so doesn't count.)  So this is a question of which optimizations and trade-offs GHC does when compiling `(x,x)` in different positions.  Someone else may know the precise reason in these cases.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I feel like your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @Codygman If you think so. I don't really know more about it, though, so I had sort of been hoping for "someone else" to show up.

Answer (score 2):

Because `(,)` is a constructor, the difference makes no difference to Haskell's semantics (`:sprint` gives access to internal thunk implementation details so doesn't count.) So this is a question of which optimizations and trade-offs GHC does when compiling `(x,x)` in different positions. Someone else may know the precise reason in these cases.