# How to parse array into tuple with aeson?

Tags: json, haskell, serialization, aeson

If I have an array `["addTask", {"id": "1", "description": "d", "dependsOn": [], "dependentTasks": []}]`.

```
data Task = Task
    { id :: String
    , description :: String
    , dependsOn :: [String]
    , dependentTasks :: [String]
    } deriving (Eq, Show, Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON)
type Change = Storage -> Storage
addTask :: Task -> Change
addTask (Task id desc dep dept) = insert id (Task id desc dep dept)
```

How can I create a parser that would produce a addTask from that?

```
instance FromJSON (Storage -> Storage) where
    parseJSON (Array v) = do
        name <- parseJSON $ v V.! 0 :: Just String
        task <- parseJSON $ v V.! 1 :: Just Task
        return (addTask task)
```

This is my current attempt which doesn't work.

Comment: If your attempt does not work - please describe what error/behaviour you are getting vs expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go on and parse the Array into a Tuple `(String,Task)` and then use simple pattern matching, you might need to specify the type of "addTask" if you are using `OverloadedStrings`, which can be done with `ScopedTypeVariables` (just add it to the left hand side of the `.. :: (String, Task) <- parse..`).

```
instance FromJSON (Storage -> Storage) where
    parseJSON v = do ("addTask",t) <- parseJSON v
                     return $ addTask t
```

Note: I did not compile or test this code

### Edit

Using alternative is really easy you just define two parsers and combine them

```
instance FromJSON (Storage -> Storage) where
    parseJSON v = let addP = do ("addTask",t) <- parseJSON v
                                return $ addTask t
                      rmP = do ("rmTask",n) <- parseJSON v
                               return $ rmTask n
                   in addP <|> rmP
```

I am assuming that `rmTask  :: Int -> Change` otherwise cou can always `case` on the first element of the tuple.

Comment: This works, thanks! I Should probably ask another question, but still, can you explain how to use Alternative here? I mean if the string is `"addTask" ` then return` addTask t` if it fails (for example it was `["removeTask", "id"]` try another parser etc. From the tutorials I probably can define a `Parser` that does so, but how to do that with this `parseJSON` - I'm not sure.

Comment: @user1685095 Updated